# How can I insert a decimal separator "." after two digit in a specif column in R?

Tags: r, decimal, edit

I have a data.frame with two column in which there are numbers in the following format:

Latitude     Longitude

-300663      -512344

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9JMo.png)

I wish insert a "." after two digits to convert to a decimal number, like:

Latitude     Longitude

-30.0663      -51.2344

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APD2l.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: If the column type is numeric, just divide by 10000? For example `yourdata$Latitude <- yourdata$Latitude / 10000`.

Comment: Based on the pictures, you may need 100000 (not 10000), but perhaps that's not consistent. Danielle, however your data is coming in, I suggest you go back to the source and determine why it's coming in that way to begin with. This ambiguity is going to cast doubt in the future.

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much!! I´ll check the source data

Answer (score 0):

**As someone above already noted, you can simply scale the variable by dividing it by whatever number you choose**. Just wanted to add that if you are only looking to explicitly turn something from an integer into a decimal format, you can also use `format`, like so:

```
x <- 40000
formatted.x <- format(x,
       nsmall = 4) # how many digits after the decimal
formatted.x
```

Which gives you what you want:

```
[1] "40000.0000"
```

However, if you check the `class` of the variable saved:

```
class(formatted.x)
```

You will find it is formatted to be a character variable, which can be annoying if you try to treat it like a decimal. Another option if you want all numbers in R to have more/less decimals is to manually change the options in R.

```
options(scipen=1000) # changes scientific notation
options(digits=5) # changes number of digits
```

**Generally speaking, I wouldn't advise doing either of these for your specific purpose**, but figured I would note these as other ways this can be achieved.